# Space separated arguments in bash

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash  

ret=`zenity --entry `  

zenity --entry --text=$ret
```

Here second instruction only prints first word of the string. How do I take string which can contain white spaces ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this:

```
zenity --entry "--text=$ret"
```

That should present the entire `--text=thing with spaces in it` as a single argument.

Of course, your `zenity` executable must still be able to handle arguments with spaces in them but that would be a *different* issue.

By way of example, see the following script executable:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "[$1]" "[$2]"
```

When you run it without and with quotes, you get the following results:

```
pax> ./testprog.sh two args
[two] [args]

pax> ./testprog.sh "one arg"
[one arg] []
```

Comment: ret=`zenity --entry "--text=$ret"`. still does not work.. do I have to escape the double quotes???

Comment: @KaunteyaSuryawanshi: no, why are you changing the _first_ line (the one starting with `ret=`)? That was used to set `ret`. Change the _second_ line, the one that _uses_ `ret`, the one you stated wasn't working.